# There and to there/thereto

Tags: adverbs

Please, help me to solve this moment, which has been torturing me for a long time

The sentence:

-Where are you, he can't see you, you are already going somewhere there or only to there?

I mean I want to separate the word "there" for 2 meanings:

1) Already at the place - there

2) Or moving in direction to the place = to there

But I see the latter one really seldom. It makes me feel deplorable. Don't people use it? Then how should I distinguish them?

"I am going there" - you are already at the place or only going to there!?=(

I believe in your wisdom, friends.

Comment: Without "to". You can tell the difference bewteen "I am going there" and "I am there" from the verb usage.

Comment: But "I am there" doesn't tell anything to person about my activity.
Maybe I am there and at the same time I am going back and forth waiting. But I din't mention "back and forth", but only "I am going there" when "I am there" doesn't include any physical addition to the sentence.

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko from this question I think you're asking how you express "going"  (as in, "moving around") while you're in a particular place and confined to that place? I don't think you could use "going" by itself in this case. You could say "I am going back and forth [like you said] here" or you could be more specific about what type of movement you're engaged in: "I'm walking/running/jogging/etc. *around* over here". I think you'd have to use a phrase like "back and forth" or "around" to indicate movement within a confined space.

Comment: But even the phrase "I go back and forth here" doesn't let me be sure for 100% what is meant here:

1) I go back somewhere and then return (to)here

2) I go back and forth already right here within 2 metres.

It's like two people, one of them saying:

1) Go back and forth here, meaning in the range of 3 metres ("here" 
relates to both "back" and "forth"

2) Go back and forth here, meaning going back for 150 metres and forth (to) here ("here" relates only to forth cause "back" is out of the range.


2) Or he goes back and forth there every mon

Answer (score 0):

I would say the verb "to go" has direction built into it.

> "I am going there"

means I am going *towards* or *to* "there", wherever "there" is (as opposed to "here," where I am now).

> "I am there"

means I am at that place ("there") already. People usually wouldn't say this to mean they are in a particular location, though. Instead, it's more likely they would say "I am *here*." (since "here" is by definition the speaker's current location.) "There" usually means "someplace that is not the place I am in right now." A person might say "I am *already* there," to mean they started going to another place ("there") and have arrived. Or, "I am *almost* there," meaning they are on the way to that place but have not arrived yet.

Comment: Okay, let's change the verb for "send" for instance.

-What about that room?
-I send the letters there.

How should I get it?
I send the letters already being in that place(already being there) or I send them "to there" not being in that place originally?

It may be hard to find the perfect exmaple with the equal rights of the each variant to be in, but the idea itself is interesting for me.

Comment: I think you might be confusing "from there" and "there" ? If you say "I am sending a letter *from there*," that means you're located "there" and sending a letter *to* somewhere else (not "there"). If you say "I am sending a letter *there*, that means you are *not* located "there" and are sending a letter *to* wherever "there" is. You wouldn't normally say "to there" as the "to" is implicit. Does that help?

Comment: Okay, let's imagine there is a room with two boxes.
I come to that room and take the letters one by one from the first box and send them to the second one. It's like changing the box.
Being outside the room and having said "I send the letters from there" means the letters achieve the B point which is outside the original space but in my situation both A and B point and I myself are in the same area - in the room. I guess it would be I send them there.
But if I step out of the room and send the letter into it's like sending it to there. 
What about this example?=)

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko I think what you're asking is how to distinguish doing an action *in* a certain place as opposed to doing an action where something goes *to* a certain place. Right? "I sent it there" will pretty much always mean "I sent it *to* there." If you want to say something that means "I sent it while I was located over there," you would say "I sent it *from* there,"  or more verbosely, "I sent it *while I was* there." Does that answer your question? In English, "send to there" has the same meaning as "send there" but just sounds redundant.

Comment: If a person will(one more moment) say "I sent it while I was located over there" - I don't know what he means. Either sending something along the territory of "there" or sending behind the territories of it

Even "behind". I throw a rock behind the house or to behind the house

Behind the house should mean I'm behind the house myself and throw the rocks there

To behind should mean I am not behind the house yet but throw the rocks in the direction of it

I sent it from there should mean "it" is not on the territory of sending but it can be still there, it's the confusion

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko again, I think (as I understand it) your confusion is about the fact that in English, using "to" does not change the meaning in any of your example sentences, and often sounds ungrammatical. "I throw a rock behind the house" means "I am throwing the rock *from* wherever I am *to* the location "behind the house." You would not normally say "to behind the house". You *would* say "I throw the rock *from* behind the house" to mean "I am behind the house now and this is where I am throwing the rock." Please correct me if this is not what you're asking about.

Comment: But "I throw the rock from behind the house" would mean (as I see it):

"I am behind the house now and this is where I am throwing the rock from"

But I am not throwing it out of the location "behind the house" it's still wtihin it. "Behind the house" area is long and the rock which is thrown doesn't cross the borders of this territory while "from behind" will probably mean the rock crosses the border and flies (to) somewhere else.

Comment: @Michael Azarenko I think when you say “I throw the rock from behind the house”- the rock could still land somewhere that’s also behind the house- we don’t know where it goes. Or it might land somewhere far away. It is definitely possible English has limits in its ability to describe these distinctions compared with your native language.

Comment: Okay, I got the "behind" moment.
What about "under".
We have a bridge and a road thereunder(can I say thus, by the way?).
We see a car which is moving "to under" the bridge. It's not there yet, but it's going to be there. How should it be said in English instead of "to under"? Cause it can't be just "under", I think, because it's not under yet, it's only going to be moving under the bridge, but not there yet.

Comment: By the way, about "to there" again. What about this:

A:Did you get to that park to see the oak?
B:No, I didn't get to there, because I always go to there but find a good shop and forget about the park.(here it's meant that he is always on his way to the park but never is there. He only goes to there but never reaches it).
C:There's no oak in the park. I am homeless and live right there, every time when I go there, I see no oaks.(here it's meant the person goes within this area, he goes there cause he is already there and isn't on his way to there because of already being in this point)

Comment: So when you talk about going "to" somewhere but not reaching it, you would probably use *toward(s)*, as in "I went *towards* the park but didn't reach it." *Towards* means something like "in the direction of" or "approaching". As for "I live right there, every time when I go there..." - I am not sure what you mean by "go". How can someone go somewhere if they are already there? What exactly do you have in mind that person C would be doing?

Comment: So I can change the phrase "go to there" for "go towards there" and it will be absolutely correct?
But there should be "toward(s)" only with pronouns, not normal nouns like "park"?
You mean it's okay to say "I go to\toward(s) the park" but the only way to say "go to there" is not with "to" but with "toward(s)?
The person C walks within the park, from one corner to a different one, he makes the steps on the very territory but doesn't step out. And because of this I said "go there" like "within there" for "within the park" or "along the park" but without any "within" or "along", just "there".