# To behind, to under

Tags: prepositions

I can be behind the house and throw stones:

**I am throwing stones behind the house**

If I am in front of the house and throwi the stones onto the territory which is behind the house, I should say something like:

**I am throwing the stones to behind the house**

But it seems to be wrong

Once I had a similar question with **there** and **to there**

I was asking about

**You go there or only to there**

And some good person told me there was a word **"thither"** which was archaic but it suited perfectly. Is there any archaic word for **"to behind"**

Because the same problem happens with **"under"**

**The car is going under the bridge**

Where is the car?

**It's on its way to under the bridge**

OR

**It's already under the bridge and is going somewhither?**

Comment: Grammatically all are possible *to there, to behind, to under*. But *to under* to express the location, is barely used or I have ever came across.

Answer (score 1):

I recall [this post of yours](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/196505/there-and-to-there-thereto) where similar questions were brought up. As I may have mentioned there, *to* + *(other preposition)* generally sounds unnatural. Usually the meaning you want to convey is understood if you omit the *to* and just use the other preposition:

> I am throwing the stones **behind** the house.
>
> The car is headed **under** the bridge.

If you want to use *to* you should opt for a noun phrase rather than another preposition:

> I am throwing the stones **to the back of the house**.
>
> The car is headed **to the place under the bridge**.

Answer (score 0):

If you were indeed throwing stones to the back of the house, you would presumably be `throwing stones _over_ the house`, but more likely you mean `round the side` which might be `throwing stones _past_ the house` or more likely `throwing stones into the back garden`.

`The car is going under the bridge` - fine.

`The (car) is on its way to the bridge` - no need for `under`.

`It's already under the bridge, and on its way` - I've heard of `hither` but not `somewhither`, certainly not common/natural.